# Duas funções javascript na mesma página

Tags: php, javascript, html, dropdown, span

bom dia! Estou com um probleminha no meu código e sou novata na área de programação, não sei se a minha dúvida é bem essa, mas, vou mostrar o código pra vocês e descrever como quero chegar ao meu objetivo:

´´´

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> aPETrecho </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />

<!--- Codigo javascript do Login -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#login-trigger').click(function() {
            $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('active');

            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
            else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
        })
    });
</script>
```

```
    <!--- Titulo -->
    <div>
        <img src="imagens/logo_title.png">
    </div>

    <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) { ?>
        <section>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li id="login">
                        <a id="login-trigger" class="" href="#">
                            Login <span>▼</span>
                        </a>
                        <div id="login-content" class="">
                            <form class="" method="POST" action="formularios/login.php">
                                <fieldset id="inputs">
                                    <input id="usuario" type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" required>
                                    <input id="senha" type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required>
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset id="actions">
                                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Entrar">
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="signup">
                        <a href="formularios/formUsuario.php">Cadastre-se!</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>

    <?php } else { ?>
        <section>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li id="painel">
                        <a id="painel-trigger" class="" href="">
                            Conta <span>▼</span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="painel-content">
                            <a href="usuario/pagUsuario.php">Perfil</a>
                            <a href="formularios/sair.php">Sair</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
    <?php } ?>
```

´´´

Tô tentando usar o código script que está no head para que quando o usuário esteja logado, ele possa clicar no span "Conta" e abra o painel com as opções "Perfil" e "Sair", o de Login funciona, mas o do "Conta" não está funcionando! Já tentei copiar o código script e mudar as id's, já tentei colocar o código dentro do body, já coloquei o código de cabeça pra baixo, nenhum deu certo! Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 0):

Você diz já ter tentado mudar os ids e não ter dado certo, mas isso é exatamente o que precisa ser feito:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login-trigger').click(function() {
        $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
        else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
    })
    
    $('#painel-trigger').click(function() {
        $(this).next('#painel-content').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
        else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> aPETrecho </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <!--- NAVEGAÇÃO -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
    <!--- Titulo -->
    <div>
      <img src="imagens/logo_title.png">
    </div>
    <section>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li id="login">
            <a id="login-trigger" class="" href="#">
              Login <span>▼</span>
            </a>
            <div id="login-content" class="">
              <form class="" method="POST" action="formularios/login.php">
                <fieldset id="inputs">
                  <input id="usuario" type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" required>
                  <input id="senha" type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="actions">
                  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Entrar">
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="signup">
            <a href="formularios/formUsuario.php">Cadastre-se!</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
    <section>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li id="painel">
            <a id="painel-trigger" class="" href="#">
              Conta <span>▼</span>
            </a>
            <div id="painel-content">
              <a href="usuario/pagUsuario.php">Perfil</a>
              <a href="formularios/sair.php">Sair</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
</html>
```

Algumas dicas:

No seu HTML você definiu `login-content` como um id, porém `painel-content` está definido como uma classe. O `#` é o seletor de ids, enquanto o `.` é o seletor de classes. Se você utilizar `$('#painel-content')` não vai funcionar, ou utilize `$('.painel-content')`, ou então defina `painel-content` como um id.

O `href` do seu `painel-trigger` está vazio. Se você clica-lo, será redirecionado para uma outra página.

---

Agora para deixar o código menos engessado, você também pode criar uma função mais genérica para os seus menus:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function toggle() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
        else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
    }

    $('#login-trigger').click(toggle)
    $('#painel-trigger').click(toggle)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> aPETrecho </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <!--- NAVEGAÇÃO -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
    <!--- Titulo -->
    <div>
      <img src="imagens/logo_title.png">
    </div>
    <section>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li id="login">
            <a id="login-trigger" class="" href="#">
              Login <span>▼</span>
            </a>
            <div id="login-content" class="">
              <form class="" method="POST" action="formularios/login.php">
                <fieldset id="inputs">
                  <input id="usuario" type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuário" required>
                  <input id="senha" type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="actions">
                  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Entrar">
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="signup">
            <a href="formularios/formUsuario.php">Cadastre-se!</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
    <section>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li id="painel">
            <a id="painel-trigger" class="" href="#">
              Conta <span>▼</span>
            </a>
            <div id="painel-content">
              <a href="usuario/pagUsuario.php">Perfil</a>
              <a href="formularios/sair.php">Sair</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
</html>
```

Comment: Sempre são minimos detalhes que faz a gente se atrapalhar, né? hahaha
Muito obrigada, consegui resolver o problema!